# wireless authentication successes when it shouldn't

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-driver

Below is the log from the device that I tried to connect to Access Point.
I set the correct SSID, but false key to the device.
What i expected was wireless connection should be failed at the authentication stage.
But the truth was it successes and even associated.
And right after that AP sent deauth message with the reason code that says previous Auth was not valid.... Which doesn't really make sense to me.
Is there an option or way to make AP proper authentication at the first stage?

```
[ 9063.262757] wlan0: authenticate with a8:5e:45:ec:b2:dc
[ 9063.274541] wlan0: send auth to a8:5e:45:ec:b2:dc (try 1/3)
[ 9063.282261] wlan0: authenticated
[ 9063.289370] wlan0: associate with a8:5e:45:ec:b2:dc (try 1/3)
[ 9063.300880] wlan0: RX AssocResp from a8:5e:45:ec:b2:dc (capab=0x511 status=0 aid=1)
[ 9063.309820] wlan0: associated
[System        ] WLAN signal is recovered(5).
[ 9067.345707] wlan0: disassociated from a8:5e:45:ec:b2:dc (Reason: 2)
```

Comment: I am using WPA2-Personal for security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's normal. This authentication phase was only used for WEP networks (if you remember APs used to have a setting for "open system" vs "shared key"). All WPA networks behave as "open" networks in this regard.

The actual WPA authentication is done in the same style as Ethernet's 802.1X, by exchanging special L2 data frames over the already-associated connection. (Indeed it even uses the same format as 802.1X, even for WPA-PSK. You would be able to see them in Wireshark as 'EAPOL' packets.)

In the 802.1X model, a client that is connected but not yet authenticated – e.g. Ethernet cable plugged in, or Wi-Fi station associated – is a "closed port" which is *only* allowed to send EAPOL frames to the authenticator (switch or AP) but blocked from everything else.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!
But is there a way that I can confirm that authentication is truly done on device side?
should i wait few sec and make sure that deauth message is not coming from AP side?

Comment: Run wpa_supplicant in debug mode (e.g. with the `-d` option), it's the program that's handling authentication, so it will show the EAPOL exchange in *much* greater detail. IWD should have an equivalent option.